# How to keep a user logged in until browser is closed or they log out

Tags: php, session, cookies, browser

Below I have 5 php scripts going in order from when user logs in to when user logs out. Now what I am doing at the moment is that I am using `$SESSION` to determine which user is logged in and then using the session_gcmaxlife to add extra time so that the session does not expire for 12 hours. So that means the user can stay logged in for 12 hours for which after that amount of time it will log the user out automatically. This is just a very basic why of producing a login system.

But what I want to do is be able to keep the user logged in for unlimited amount of time until they have either clicked on the logout link or have closed down the browser. What my question is that with the minimum amount of code change as possible, how can the codes below be altered so that they keep a user logged in until they logout or close the browser?

Below are the php scripts in order to show what is currently happening:

1. **teacherlogin.php** (This is the script where the user enters in their loggin details to log into the application)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php

// connect to the database
include('connect.php');
include('member.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

  // required variables (make them explciit no need for foreach loop)
  $teacherusername = (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) ? $_POST['teacherusername'] : '';
  $teacherpassword = (isset($_POST['teacherpassword'])) ? $_POST['teacherpassword'] : '';
  $loggedIn = false;
  $active = true;

  if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){
      echo "You are already Logged In: <b>{$_SESSION['teacherforename']} {$_SESSION['teachersurname']}</b> | <a href='./menu.php'>Go to Menu</a> | <a href='./teacherlogout.php'>Logout</a>";
  }
  else{

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $teacherpassword = md5(md5("g3f".$teacherpassword."rt4"));  

    // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
    $query = "SELECT TeacherId, TeacherForename, TeacherSurname, TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword, Active FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ? AND TeacherPassword = ? LIMIT 1";
    // prepare query
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$teacherusername,$teacherpassword);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(); 
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherId, $dbTeacherForename,$dbTeacherSurname,$dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword, $dbActive);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
      if ($teacherusername == $dbTeacherUsername && $teacherpassword == $dbTeacherPassword) {
if ($dbActive == 0) {
    $loggedIn = false;
    $active = false;
    echo "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
}else {
    $loggedIn = true;
    $active = true;
      $_SESSION['teacherid'] = $dbTeacherId;
      $_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $dbTeacherUsername;
}
      }
    }

    if ($loggedIn == true){
      $_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $dbTeacherForename;
      $_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $dbTeacherSurname;
      header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;
      die();
    }

    if (!$loggedIn && $active && isset($_POST)) {
    echo "<span style='color: red'>The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again</span>";
    }

       /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
  }
?>
```

**2. member.php** (This script contains `$SESSION` variables to determine which user is logged in. This is a very important script and is included (using `include(member.php) to be able to determine if a user is already logged in or not)

```
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherforename'])) {

$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $_SESSION['teacherforename'];

}

if (isset($_SESSION['teachersurname'])) {

$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $_SESSION['teachersurname'];

}

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherid'])) {

      $userid = $_SESSION['teacherid'];

  }

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {

      $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];

  }

        ?>
```

**3. menu.php** (This is the menu page where the user can select which page they wish to navigate to by using the menu displyed)

```
   <?php

    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
    ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
    ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
    require_once 'init.php'; 

     ini_set('display_errors',1); 
     error_reporting(E_ALL);


    session_start();

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Menu</title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">

            </head>

            <?php

            include('member.php');

            if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){

    include('teachername.php');
            ?>

            <body>

                            <?php
            include('noscript.php');
            ?>

            <ul>
            <li><a href="create_session.php">Create an Assessment</a></li>
            </ul>

            <?php

        }else{

            echo "Please Login to Access this Page | <a href='./teacherlogin.php'>Login</a>";

        }

        ?>
```

4 **createsession.php** (This page is where users are able to create an exam, only a logged in user can access this page)

```
<?php

        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
        ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
        ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
        ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
        require_once 'init.php'; 

        session_start();

        include('member.php');

        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Create a New Assessment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="create_sessionStyles.css">

        <?php

        if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){ 
        ?>

        <script>
        function showConfirm(){

        var confirmMsg=confirm(Are you Sure?);

        if (confirmMsg==true)
        {
        submitform();   
        }
        }

        function submitform()
        {

        $.post("insertsession.php", $("#sessionForm").serialize() ,function(data){
        var sessionFormO = document.getElementById("sessionForm");
        sessionFormO.submit();
        }); 

        }


        </script>
        </head>
        <body>


        <form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">
        <p><strong>1: Number of Assessments you Require:</strong> <input type="text" id="sessionNo" name="sessionNum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" /><br/><span id="sessionNoAlert"></span></p>
        <p><strong>2: Duration:</strong> <input type="text" id="durationpicker" name="durationChosen" readonly="readonly" /></p>
        <p><strong>3: Date:</strong> <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dateChosen" readonly="readonly" /></p>
        <p><strong>4: Start Time:</strong> <input type="text" id="timepicker" name="timeChosen" readonly="readonly" /><span class="timepicker_button_trigger"><img src="Images/clock.gif" alt="Choose Time" /></span>    
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function myClickHandler(){ 
        if(validation()){ 
        showConfirm(); 
        } 
        }


        </script>

        <?php

        }
        }
        }else{ 

        echo "Please Login to Access this Page | <a href='./teacherlogin.php'>Login</a>";

        }
        ?>

        </body>
```

5 **teacherlogout.php** (Finally this is the logout page, when the user clicks on a logout link (which is only displayed in menu.php at moment) then it will go to this page where it displays a message and performs the log out by destroying the session)

```
<?php

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
require_once 'init.php'; 

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);


session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Menu</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">

</head>

<?php

include('member.php');

?>

<body>

<?php

if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){
session_destroy();
echo "You have been Logged Out | <a href='./home.php'>Home</a>";
}

else {

echo "You are Not Logged In";

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post samples of code containing relevant parts, not everything. Too much code here.

Comment: session will destroy automatically when browser closed, browsers delete all session id cookie when user close it, so i think just one thing you have to change, remove session extra time!, However you have big security issues with your login page, there is SQL injection bug

Comment: @MohammadAhmad can I ask where the SQL injection bug is?

Comment: i think when you received $teacherusername

Comment: I don't understand where this myth started that session id cookies are deleted whenever a browser is closed. That doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session id is stored as a cookie on the clients machine. When the client browser closes the session cookie is cleared. If you want the user to stay logged in while inactive-indefinitely you'll have to do something with ajax request on a setTimeout or a hidden iframe with an HTTP-EQUIV refresh meta tag to keep incrementing/refreshing the server-side session expiration. When the client browser is closed the hidden iframe or ajax refresher will no longer run and the session will expire.

Comment: Hi, sorry for lateness, I will probably need sample code to see what needs to be done because I have never done this before when it comes to keeping users logged in until they log out. Can you please make a sample code which can be implemented with my code, it would be very helpful. Take your time no rush, it will help me and future users who hasn't done this before